# Bevel Vertices on Plane

Tags: modeling

I'm just trying to make a simple door.
I started with a plane, scaled it. Then I wanted to bevel the 2 top corners, but I can only bevel in proportion to the plane. That means the bevel is not 45°. Is there any workaround for that? <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get expected result, you need to first select the object, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Scale, to apply the scale. (I'm not sure why, and it seems not being documented, but it works this way)